# Всплывающие окна по ссылкам, извлекаемым из базы данных

Tags: jquery, php, css

Как создать окно, всплывающее по ссылке, что выводится в цикле с базы?

Есть задание: вывести ссылки на клиентов, когда на них жмете всплывает окно с инфой из базы. Всплывающие окна есть, но как их к PHP привязать, не знаю. Подскажите какое-то решение. jQuery окно в форме почему-то не выводится. Спасибо.

Comment: Черес ХТМЛ и джаваскрыптъ.

Comment: @michael____1, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: фуууу, школота неграмотная

Answer (score 7):

Хороший вопрос :) Ну, для начала вам нужно изучить **JavaScript**. Ну а потом если будет желание **jQuery**. Для решения данной задачи я Вам приведу пример на **jQuery**.

Создаем **CSS** стиль:

```
#set{
   opacity: 0.9;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   background-color: #000; 
   display: block;
   position: fixed; 
   left: 0; 
   top:0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 9;
}
#mess{
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fefefe), to(#dddddd));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe, #dddddd);
   position: absolute;
   top: 30%;
   right: 35%;
   width: 30%;
   height: 22%;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 15px white;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(255, 255, 255);
   box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgb(255, 255, 255);
   z-index: 10;
   position: fixed; 
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   color: #616161;
}
```

Далее создаем скрипт на **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#set').hide();
  $('#mess').hide();

  $('#info').click(function(){
    $('#set').show(1000);
    $('#mess').fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
  });

  $('#close').click(function(){
    $('#set').hide(1000);
    $('#mess').fadeOut(1000);
  });

});
```

И на конец создаем скрипт на **php** & **html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Сюда засовываем код jQuery и CSS -->
</head>
<body>

<div id='set'></div>

<div id='mess'>
  <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klienti");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo "Логин: ".$row['login']."<br>";
    }
  ?>
  <center><a href='#' id='close'>Закрыть</a></center>
</div>

<br />

<a href='#' id='info'>Показать клиентов</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Этот код, конечно, наглядный, но все же, может быть, Вы что то поймете.

Comment: вот и не лень было...

Comment: @istem, бывает))